# Is there a way to protect against unauthorized viewing of a document in a web site?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

If I have a url as part of my website that points to a document:
https://test.abc.com/admin/reports/company.pdf

is there any way to prevent someone from just going to that URL if they are not logged/authenticated into our site?
The site has its own login username/password mechanism that was implemented where users log in.

Alas, sorry.  IIS 5.0 under Windows 2003

Comment: Please tell us what web server and/or language you're using. Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS will not protect a .pdf. What you have to do is register the .pdf extension with a .ashx that servers the file. The .ashx will require authentication and then regular .net authentication can kick in.

This post describes how to do it in detail.

http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/34535/1954